# MySQL: SUM in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I've got this table

```
CREATE TABLE `subevents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text,
  `class` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Each row can have a different value in the 'class' field.

I'd like to select any number of rows, ordered randomly, as long as the sum of the values in the 'class' field is equal to 100.

How could I accomplish it directly in the MySQL query without doing it later in PHP?

Thanks everybody!

Comment: I don't think SQL is designed for these queries...

Comment: Sounds like a variation on the subset sum problem which is NP complete: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: for aggregate functions use HAVING instead of WHERE

Comment: Sounds kind of hard to do (or quite possibly infeasible to do, as Mark points out), unless you relax some of your requirements. For example, if you relax the requirement that the sum of values be *precisely* 100, and just require it to be *at least* 100 instead, it would become fairly easy.

Comment: Imre - that's not what he wants. He wants a random element of the set {ordered lists of rows from the table such that the "class" values sum to 100}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "ordered randomly" I assume you mean that the order of the rows doesn't matter but no row can be used more than once.  So you are looking for a combination of rows in which the sum of `class` equals 100.  Use the brute force method.  Randomly generate possible solutions until you find one that works.

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE subsetsum(total)
BEGIN
    DECLARE sum INTEGER;
    REPEAT
        CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `solution`
        AS SELECT * FROM `subevents`
            WHERE 0.5 <= RAND();
        SELECT SUM(`class`) INTO sum FROM `solution`;
    UNTIL sum = total END REPEAT;
END
//
delimiter ;
CALL subsetsum(100); /* For example */
SELECT * FROM `solution`;
```

I have tested this with tables having a TINYINT column of random values and it is actually reasonably fast.  The only problem is that there is no guarantee that subsetsum() will ever return.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with only SQL...the only thing which comes to my mind is to redo a the sql query as long the sum isn't 100

But I have no clue how to select a random number of rows at once.